# TPPDF result very strange

Tags: ios, xcode

I've written two modules with TPPDF. The first is correct and the pdf is OK. With the second  (exactly the same logic), I've a strange result for the pdf file. The content is OK but the style is too bad.
all the full lines are missing and the contents are surrounded by dots red
I join a part of code
Have you an idea
Thank you very much for your help
Best regards

[image]

```
***let document = PDFDocument(format: .a4)

document.add(.headerCenter, text: "DISTRICT DU VAL DE MARNE DE FOOTBALL : CFAER ")

let headerImage = PDFImage(image: UIImage(named: "districtvdm")!,
                           size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
document.add(.headerLeft, image: headerImage)
document.add(.headerRight, image: headerImage)
document.set(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0))

let colorsDbt = (fill: UIColor.white, text: UIColor.black)
let lineStyleDbt = PDFLineStyle(type: .full, color: UIColor.white, width: 0)
let bordersDbt = PDFTableCellBorders(left: lineStyleDbt, top: lineStyleDbt, right: 
lineStyleDbt,bottom: lineStyleDbt)
let fontDbt = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
let styleRowDbt = PDFTableCellStyle(colors: colorsDbt, borders: bordersDbt, font: 
fontDbt)
let tableDbt = PDFTable(rows: 1, columns: 1)
let rowDbt = tableDbt[row: 0]
let textDbt = resultats[0] + "\n"  + "FEUILLE DE RENCONTRE"
rowDbt.content = [textDbt]
rowDbt.style = [styleRowDbt]
document.add(table: tableDbt)

let colorsTitre = (fill: UIColor.white, text: UIColor.black)
let colorsTitreGray = (fill: UIColor.systemGray5, text: UIColor.black)
let lineStyleTitre = PDFLineStyle(type: .full, color: UIColor.black, width: 2)
let bordersTitre = PDFTableCellBorders(left: lineStyleTitre, top: lineStyleTitre, right: 
lineStyleTitre,bottom: lineStyleTitre)
let fontTitre = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
let styleRowTitre = PDFTableCellStyle(colors: colorsTitre, borders: bordersTitre, font: 
fontTitre)

let tableTitre = PDFTable(rows: 1, columns: 1)
let rowTitre = tableTitre[row: 0]
let titre = resultats[6]
rowTitre.content = [titre]
rowTitre.style = [styleRowTitre]
document.add(table: tableTitre)

let table1 = PDFTable(rows: 1, columns: 1)
let row1 = table1[row: 0]
let centre = "CENTRE : " + resultats[2] + "   Date : " + resultats[3] + "     Poule : " 
+ resultats[5]
row1.content = [centre]
let colors = (fill: UIColor.white, text: UIColor.black)
let font1 = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
let styleRow1 = PDFTableCellStyle(colors: colors, borders: bordersTitre, font: font1)
row1.style = [styleRow1]
document.add(table: table1)
    
let table2 = PDFTable(rows: 1, columns: 1)
let row2 = table2[row: 0]
let resp = "RESPONSABLE DU PLATEAU : " + resultats[4]
row2.content = [resp]
let styleRow2 = PDFTableCellStyle(colors: colors, borders: bordersTitre, font: font1)
row2.style = [styleRow2]
document.add(table: table2)
let  tableEquipes = PDFTable(rows: 5, columns: 3)
tableEquipes.widths = [0.1, 0.5, 0.4]
let cellInit0 = tableEquipes[0, 0]
let cellInit1 = tableEquipes[0, 1]
let cellInit2 = tableEquipes[0, 2]
        
let znum = "N°"
let zclubs = "Equipes"
let zsignature = "Signatures des éducateurs"
       
cellInit0.content = znum.asTableContent
cellInit1.content = zclubs.asTableContent
cellInit2.content = zsignature.asTableContent
let fontBid = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)
let styleCellsBid = PDFTableCellStyle(colors: colorsTitreGray, borders: 
bordersTitre, font: fontBid)
        
cellInit0.style = styleCellsBid
cellInit1.style = styleCellsBid
cellInit2.style = styleCellsBid
.......
document.add(table: tableEquipes)***
```

Comment: Have you accidentally enabled the debug overlay (`generator.debug = true`)?

Comment: Actually I didn’t see I've enabled the debug overlay!!!

Comment: Now is corrcet!!